# How can I run commands through all Excel worksheets via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel workbook, I have two worksheets with similar structures.

I wrote VBA code that:

- converts format from the text to the data in a range;
- sorts the date in a range from oldest to the newest;
- filters in a range by the specific characters (the full name of the head of the department, e.g. J.S.Doe);
- makes active and moves the view to the top left corner cell in both worksheets;
- goes to the next worksheet and repeats the code, then goes to the previous worksheet.

```vb
Sub SuperiorsOrders()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Range("I3", Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).Sort [I2], xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="J.S.Doe"
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
    
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    
    Range("I3", Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).Sort [I2], xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="J.S.Doe"
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
    
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

To reduce the code, I tried to wrap it into the `For Each` loop statement. It still works, but only for active worksheet, not for all of them.

```vb
Sub SuperiorsOrders()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
    Range("I3", Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).Sort [I2], xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="J.S.Doe"
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
Next WS

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I searched the internet, including similar questions here, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the worksheet reference to the range in the loop otherwise `Range` always refers to the active sheet

```
    ws.Range("I3", ws.Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
   ' add the remaining lines of code starting with ws.
```

or

```
With  ws 
   .Range("I3", .Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
   ' add the remaing lines of code in the same way
End With
```

So your code would look like that

```
Sub SuperiorsOrders()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In Worksheets
        With WS
            .Range("I3", .Range("I3").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
            .Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).Sort [I2], xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            .Range("A3", "J3").End(xlDown).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="J.S.Doe"
            ' .Range("A1").Select  That is not necessary
        End With
        'Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True  <= What is that good for?
    Next WS

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: **Thank you**, a lot, Mr. @Storax!

For the code to work properly, I also had to add `a dot` before `[I2]`.

Now a problem is that `.Range("A1").Select` does not work.

I changed it to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select` but it unsurprisingly works only on active worksheet.

How can I fix it?

_(`Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True` moves the user view to the `A1` cell, for example, when I open a file that has been saved on a view about `A255`, the code will show me the top left corner of worksheet)_

Comment: If you need the Select and Goto, then add them back in...

Comment: Mr. @TimWilliams, `Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True` works well, but `.Range("A1").Select` returns an error but `CurrentSheet.Range("A1").Select` works, as it should be, only on an active worksheet. How could I fix it?

Comment: .activate ist the hint